# Getting bytes when using axios

Tags: javascript, django, axios

I'm sending post-request from front using axios

```
var data = {
    key1: value1,
};

axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'my_url',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

But on django-backend I got bytes object `b'{"key1":"value1"}'`

Is there a way to get a **json object** on the backend? Or do I need to **decode** the request?

Comment: Do not stringify, just send plain data object.

Comment: can we have a look at your django part as well?

Comment: @xpy - absolute nothing special there `def view_funct(request):
    return JsonResponce(request)`. I get check the request object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `JSON.stringify` with Axios. Axios handles it internally. Just send the plain javascript object to the backend like this

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'my_url',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    data: data,
})
```

If you do use stringify, Axios takes that string as JSON and stringifies it again internally, that why you Django is not able to decode it.

**EDIT**
As per your comment on the question, I can see you are using a simple Django view to handle the request. Django views use `WSGIRequest` object as their request parameter. Because JSON is sent as the request body, they do nothing to it (do not parse) and present original data as it is. that's why you are seeing bytes object as `request.body`. You can manually parse it using json module from python standard library like this.

```
request.data = json.loads(request.body)
```

Or if you want more API compatible request object, I recommend using `api_view` decorator from Django rest framework like this

```
@api_view(http_allowed_methods=['post'])
def func(request):
    pass
```

It will wrap your request with `Request` object from `rest_framework.request` module which will handle all parsing for you and present parsed data as `request.data`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/).

Comment: still the same, **bytes**